# Should I stop practice singing and switch to fingerstyle guitar?

Tags: guitar, voice, acoustic-guitar

I have been practising the guitar for more than a year now. I see some improvements in guitar skills like switching between cords faster, playing any simple riff and singing along while playing the guitar, etc.

I really like singing as well. I would like to be a singer-songwriter. I also like fingerstyle guitar. However what I feel now is, my singing skill sucks big time. I have recorded myself over and over again. But nothing great. I feel that my voice doesn't have a soul

Problems I found in my singing.

1. Singing in Key
2. Breathing technic sucks
3. Not native English speaker. So pronunciation is not so great.

Also, I am a full-time working person. Couldn't get Vocal training as such.

Is it possible to get to a decent vocal by training by myself? If so, could you please share some materials(Over youtube/Any online content) that I can use to teach myself?

I am 24 years old. Is it too late to learn to sing?
Should I stop practising singing and concentrate more on fingerstyle guitar?

I am totally depressed and any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Count the successful music acts without a singer.  Count the successful music acts without a fingerstyle guitarist.

And while you are at it, count the successful single-person music acts.  This is not really a question worth answering in isolation, at least when measured with the "successful" metric.

On the other hand, take a look at artists like Bob Dylan and Leonard Cohen.  Either are not particularly renowned for their singing skills but cannot in good conscience be called unsuccessful.  But their message wasn't "I want to be a singer-songwriter".  Dylan was a social warrior, Cohen was a poet.

Who are you?

Answer (score 1):

Recommendations for materials, etc. such as you request are not part of this site's remit. However, as far as singing is concerned, without hearing you - or your guitar playing for that matter, it's impossible to guide you.

My suggestion in isolation would be to conyinue learning the guitar - and do not limit yourself to one style. Learn to strum chords, play a few riffs, play finerstyle, and any other thing you are exposed to. Become more of an all-rounder.

Leave the vocals for now as the main consideration. Find another person who can do the singing, and work with them. As you do, learning and playing songs together, use the opportunity to improve your singing, I'm sure they will help.

Hate to say it, but listening to Youtube versions of what you'd like to do will help with presentation - playing, singing, and to a degree, pronunciation - albeit in a pseudo-American accent - which seems to be predominant these days!

And, as user 43445 says, there have been several 'singers' out there who couldn't be classed as 'good singers', but they got by just fine.